# PHP-CLI Command Not Found

Tags: laravel, lumen, laravel-scheduler

Now I just moved to inmotion from siteground and previously from bluehost.  I am trying to set up my laravel(lumen) application on the server.  I have been able to get everything else working but the scheduler which I just cannot seem to get to work.

This is the cron job `php -q /home/xxxxx/xxxxx/artisan schedule:run` which seem to run fine however it fails to execute the queue:work command.

I noticed on my previous hosting I had to edit the `Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Scchedule.php` file like this:

```
return $this->exec("php-cli /home/xxxxx/xxxxx/artisan {$command}", $parameters);
```

using the regular `php` command did not work for some reason I had to use `php-cli`, however with my current hosting it says "command not found" whenever I try to use the php-cli command manually and all my cron job returns in my email is this:

```
Running scheduled command: php-cli /home/xxxxx/xxxxx/artisan queue:work > '/dev/null' 2>&1 &
```

I would like to know how I can fix this and get the scheduler to work.

Yes I have php installed. (v7.0)
Yes I have the php-cli package installed. (v7.0)
My VPS server uses linox OS.

Comment: Could you please give me the result of this command `sudo find / -name php-cli` ?

Comment: There is no result when I run this command.

Answer (score 0):

You do write absolute route to `php-cli` command and `artisan` script to properly work:

```
  /usr/local/php70/bin/php-cli /home/{username}/{path-to-app}/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```